# How can I replace a certain area of an 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

```
X2d = np.array([[255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255]])


# I want to give it information about right, up, width, height where I want to manipulate it
# for example (1, 1, 2, 2)
# and I would like to get these two:

X2dresult = np.array([[255,255,255,255],
                      [255,  0,  0,255],
                      [255,  0,  0,255],
                      [255,255,255,255]])
```

I want to do something like that just in a higher dimension.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+numpy+assign+rectangle+of+2d+array+to+number) of [How to create a 2D “rect” array (square block of 1's, else 0's) in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10159178/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to slices in numpy. For example:

```
X2d = np.array([[255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255],
                [255,255,255,255]])

X2d[1:3, 1:3] = 0
```

gives you:

```
array([[255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

This works in higher dimensions too.